# Is it possible to break a Composite key?

Tags: relational-database, composite-key

Is it possible to break the composite key of a table and use one of them as a primary key for other table? If yes, then please tell me how can I do it?

Comment: by Break i meant... whether i can use one of the column in it as primary to some other table..

Answer (score 2):

Generally you use a composite key when none of the columns alone contains unique values. Since a primary key must be unique, you probably can't use just one of the columns.